# How do sites go about retrieving "new" items from rss feeds?

Tags: rss

Let's say I want to parse [Sherdog](http://www.sherdog.com/syndication.php) news feeds. Is the only way to retrieve them by parsing the public xml files? Is there not some service that sites have that "pushes" the content onto your server?

I'm under the impression the common way to do this is to setup a cron job that say, every 10 minutes hits a page such as [this](http://www.sherdog.com/rss/news.xml), and inserts items into a database if they are not already in there.

Is this the case? If not, can someone educate me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, polling RSS feeds is the de-facto standard. RSS readers and servers should support caching mechanisms (most importantly HTTP conditional GETs) to make this efficient.

An emerging approach to get rid of polling is [PubSubHubub](http://pubsubhubub.com/), which does indeed push notifications to subscribers.

Comment: Got any links for polling RSS feed best practices?

Comment: PubSubHubbub will save your bandwidth... and your CPU cycles :) Also, check http://superfeedr.com as they can turn _any_ feed into PubSubHubbub, so you do not have to poll any feed ever.

Comment: @Julien Genestoux - are you saying that PubSubHubub is now usable thanks to superfeedr? Do you use it yourself?

Comment: @Meder : we provide hubs for folks like Tumblr, Posterous, Typepad, Gowalla, Gawker, HuffPo... etc. And we susbcribe to other hubs when needed :)